# Android, run code only after the UI has been rendered for an activity

Tags: android

I know this question is on here many times, but the answer that works in all of those cases does not work for mine. When the activity starts I am taking a screenshot of the screen. I execute my code at the bottom of the onCreate. It works great 4 our of 5 times and the 5th time the screen has not rendered yet and you get a black screenshot.

My workaround is to execute the screenshot code in an AsyncTask that is started at the end of onCreate. If I put a 200ms sleep the it works 9 out of 10 times. A 500ms sleep gets it 100% of the time but you can notice the delay. This also seems like a terrible solution because that 500ms is an arbitrary number that may not work across all devices.

How can I know when the UI is rendered, so I can take my screenshot?

Comment: call View.post() and do your job in run() method

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could just grab the top decor view using [Window.getDecorView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getDecorView()) and then use [post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) on it. Using the decor view results in reusable code that can be run in any application as it does not depend on some specific [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) element being a part of the inflated layout.

The call will result in your [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) being placed in the message queue to be run on the UI thread, so **do not run long operations in the Runnable** to avoid blocking the UI thread.

#### Simple implementation - Kotlin

```
// @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    window.decorView.post {
        // TODO your magic code to be run
    }
```

#### Simple implementation - Java

```
// @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO your magic code to be run
        }

    });
```