# Android (Java): Is there an event or somethingelse that simply telling me that all GUI elements of an Activity are completely rendered and available?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

If I try to use, for example, the getHeight() method of a LinearLayout object before it is rendered I get a 0. The same happens for every gui element if they are not ready. Perhaps I make a mistake but  for solving this problem I use a ViewTreeObserver object and OnGlobalLayoutListener for every GUI element for being sure that a GUI element is ready before getting some infos from it . What I’d like to know if is there an event or other stuff that in a very simple way tells me if the entire GUI of an Activity is completely rendered and ready to use. When I used Appcelerator Titanium there was an event able to say that (I don't remember the exact name). What i read on [Android, run code only after the UI has been rendered for an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080799/android-run-code-only-after-the-ui-has-been-rendered-for-an-activity) I don't know how to apply simply to my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22312916/3290339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, run code only after the UI has been rendered for an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080799/android-run-code-only-after-the-ui-has-been-rendered-for-an-activity)

Comment: What if you use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` for the root view of your activity? For the root to be ready, all its children have to be ready as well.