# Strange behavior of a bottom navigation view when is set visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation, android-statusbar

I try to make an app using one activity multiple fragments pattern. I handle navigation with Navigation architecture component using a bottom navigation view. In one of the fragment I have a `Recyclerview` which displays a list of custom cards. On item click it navigates to another fragment where I need to hide the bottom navigation view.

The problem appears when I navigate back and set the bottom navigation view visible again. The bar seems to appear in two steps giving the feeling of lag. (first time appears just 60% of the bottom navigation view).

The behavior seems to be related with the status bar. When I change the theme to full screen or I set `windowTranslucentStatus=true`, everything behaves okay. In addition, first time the nav bar seems to be with exactly `24dp` smaller, that is the dimension of status bar.

Have you any idea what can I do?
PS. I'm new on stackoverflow and this is my first question. I'm glad to join this wonderful community.

Comment: try to add some delay before displaying `BottomNavigationView` and run it on separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay is one way to go, but I wouldn't suggest that.

I am assuming that the your navigation view is rendered before the entire activity is rendered, which is causing it to be rendered again after the UI is rendered. Why don't you try setting the visibility after the UI is rendered, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080799/android-run-code-only-after-the-ui-has-been-rendered-for-an-activity)